# Delete many rows from a table using SN in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp, localhost, sql-delete

I am only IT Support with only basic knowledge with Queries. I want to delete many table entries which are Serial Number row from my table using ac_serial_number.

Currently, I'm using

```
DELETE FROM `asset_comparison` WHERE `asset_comparison`.`ac_serial_number` = 'SGH511XXXX'
DELETE FROM `asset_comparison` WHERE `asset_comparison`.`ac_serial_number` = '6CM451XXXX'
```

but I have about 1000 serial number which I want to delete. my method will going to take some hours.

Can you tell me to delete efficiently ?

Comment: be clear and specific. Is that MySQL or MSSQL, In where what is the column_name

Comment: DELETE from ac_comparison where 3CQ301XXXX; is invalid sql should probably be DELETE from ac_comparison where ac_serial_number = '3CQ301XXXX';

Comment: ac_serial_number doesn't look like a number of any sort where does the serial bit come into it?

Comment: sorry, I forget to write. fix by me re-write code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's only about 1000 ?

Then you could do it using one DELETE with an IN criteria.

For example:

```
DELETE FROM asset_comparison 
WHERE ac_serial_number IN (
 'SGH511XXXX'
,'6CM451XXXX'
-- Add more here
);
```

Comment: @biiboy Thx for the rep. Btw, if the SQL would become to big with too many numbers? An alternative could be to load the numbers into a temporary table and then use a query inside that IN that selects the numbers from that temp table.